# The difference between "gonna be doing it" and "gonna do it"?

Tags: differences

I got a question when one of my Australian friends said "I'm gonna be working on this[the project] tomorrow".

What's the difference between "gonna be doing" vesus "gonna do" which I was always told? What is the point using countinuous tense there? Many thanks.

Comment: I would hear "going to be doing it" as "I will be busy tomorrow because I will be doing it", while "going to do it" is a simpler "I will do it tomorrow"

Comment: Basically the difference between _gonna be doing_ and _gonna do_ is the difference between the experience of working and the experience of being done with the work. _Do_ means 'finish' in this sentence; you might not finish tomorrow if you're only gonna be working on it.

Comment: Hi John, I love your explanation. That helps me a lot! Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm **going to be doing** this[the project] tomorrow". – This speaks of a time when he has started the project, but has not yet finished it. The speaker is saying that he will be in the process of doing it.

"I'm **going to do** this[the project] tomorrow". – This speaks of the instance of work on the project as a single unit that encompasses the moment before he starts and the moment after he finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I think "*gonna be doing something*"/"*going to be doing something*" emphasizes the moment that action takes place, or its duration, and will likely only be used for actions that take a substantial amount of time, as it indicates that another event referred to in the given context might occur during that period of time.

> *I'm going to be taking out the trash.*

vs.

> *I'm going to take out the trash.*

Looking at this comparative example, the first expression stresses that this action somehow influences something else that has been brought up. It might take place concurrently, or interfere with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joachim. That makes sense!